# pagination to move from left to right to left. (swiper slider)

Tags: javascript, css, pagination, slider, swiper.js

in the swiper sliderin mousewheel demo, the pagination is right-justified. I want to show the pagination bar on the left.
here is the sample code. Can you help me?
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lbej0o?file=%2Findex.html

```html
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
```

this is how i created a div and class. I assigned these css values to this class but the result did not change

```css
.swiper-pagination {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   ball: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `--swiper-pagination-right` and `--swiper-pagination-left` for the element:

```css
.swiper-pagination {
  --swiper-pagination-right: auto;
  --swiper-pagination-left: 8px;
}
```

Try it:

```js
new Swiper('.swiper', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination'
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-pagination {
  --swiper-pagination-right: auto;
  --swiper-pagination-left: 8px;
}


/* Demo only */

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.swiper {
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"><div>Slide 1</div></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><div>Slide 2</div></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><div>Slide 3</div></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><div>Slide 4</div></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><div>Slide 5</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working bro

Comment: its working you just hold it and move up

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css code:

```
.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets, 
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
   right: auto;
   left: 8px;
}
```